# Is there an official Navision 2015 Application Designer Guide?

Tags: dynamics-nav, dynamics-nav-2015

I have been able to download a Dynamics NAV PDF that is stamped for version 5.00.  We are using NAV 2015 (version 8).  I can find stuff on MSDN, but was wondering if there was an official PDF somewhere so when I'm not connected to the Internet, I can still read through the documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is nothing offline unfortunately.
Everything is on MSDN for Dynamics NAV even the Application Help.
You can download something "semi-offical" from here: [CAL-Coding-Guidelines-at-Microsoft-Development-Center-Copenhagen.pdf](https://msdnshared.blob.core.windows.net/media/MSDNBlogsFS/prod.evol.blogs.msdn.com/CommunityServer.Components.PostAttachments/00/10/58/54/01/CAL%20Coding%20Guidelines%20at%20Microsoft%20Development%20Center%20Copenhagen.pdf)
But most of the guidelines are still the same since Version 5 (even the original version 2...)

Cheers!